# User authentication token not accepted, but working in postman

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, swift3, alamofire

Getting response code 406 from api response. On Postman api run successfully, but in code it gives result as:

```
success : "{\"message\": \"User authentication token not accepted\"}"
```

and gets error message nil.

I am not getting, other GET api's are working but not this one and this one is working in postman also but not in code.

With the same token other api's are working then why this api getting this error message. And a common method used for api hit.

Below is code:

```
 var strToken : String = ""
        if let access_token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token"){
            let tokenValue = String(format: "Token %@", access_token);
            strToken = tokenValue
        }

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": strToken,
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        Alamofire.request(strCompleteURL, headers : headers).responseString { response in
            print("Got Alamofire Response: ", response.result)
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                if let data = response.data{
                    self.responseJR.responseCode = response.response?.statusCode
                    self.processResult(data);
                }
            }
            else if response.result.isFailure {
                if let error : Error = response.result.error{
                    self.responseJR.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription;
                }
                if let res = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                {
                    self.responseJR.infoResponse = res as AnyObject?;
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.didFinishServerCommunicationWithSuccess(self.responseJR)
                }
            }
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1
Try this Almofire request format

send parameters as nil if GET request 
send parameters if POST request

```
  Alamofire.request(endPoint, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers:setHeader())
            .responseJSON { response in
}
```

Do check if your auth token you are providing is correct

Comment: same response, no change

Comment: There is no issue with the request as it is getting response from service....the get  api you are calling is it yours? .....if yes then debug at service end. As you can see error is specifying that token is incorrect so there is function which is  throwing this error because of some issue.....

Comment: have you got any solution @iPhone7 . I am facing same issue

Comment: same problem here, any solution?